# how to write stored procedure with two different queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Actually i am a beginner in database ..
I have written a stored procedure in which I want to get results in c# winform app from two different tables using if else , for instance I have two tables with one column in common that is 'comp_number' .. now I have written a stored procedure which executes on a button click event

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[complainVehicle_sp]
as
DECLARE @compno int


if @compno is not null  

begin

    select compno,compdate,regno,engineno,mcode from dbo.complainVehicle 
    where compno =  @compno 

end

else 

begin

   select compno,recoverydt,recoverytime,statuscode from dbo.complainRecovery
   where compno =  @compno   

end
```

---

Now I want that if `Compno` matches table `complainVehicle` it shows me the result against this , and if it matches with table `complainRecovery` it shows me the result against that record else it will display no record ..

here is my c# code

```
  string str = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=----;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=----;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;";
            SqlConnection cnn = null;


            try
            {
                cnn = new SqlConnection(str);
                cnn.Open(); //open the connection

            }


            catch (SqlException err) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cnn != null)
                {
                    cnn.Close(); 
                }
            } 


            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)

            {MessageBox.Show("No Record");}

            else if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length  > 0)  
            {

                cnn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = cnn;
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.CommandText = "complainVehicle_sp";
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@compno", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                cnn.Close();
```

As I write `compno` in textbox and click sumbit it shows an error 
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Procedure complainVehicle_sp has no parameters and arguments were supplied.`

... i would appreciate you all for this help .. thanks in advance guys

Comment: Get the `@compno` as Input parameter. select inside else part is never going to fetch any result. Really not sure what you are trying to achieve. Whether you need result from both the tables when the input is matched with the `compno` column

Comment: i want to check basically whose compno matches with , then it may fetch results accordingly , if compno i have given to textnox matches with dbo.complainvehicle.compno then it show records from this table else it matches with dbo.complainrecovery,compno it shows the record from that table

Comment: What if the input is present in both the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `DECLARE @compno int`, which creates a local variable within the procedure body. The `@compno` variable is not accessible from outside of the stored procedure context, and it means nothing to the C# code that is invoking the procedure:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add(
    "@compno", 
    System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
```

So, to address your issue, first, change the stored procedure to **accept parameters**.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[complainVehicle_sp]
-- declare a parameter @compono to the procedure
    @compno INT
as ...
BEGIN
    IF @compno IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT compno,compdate,regno,engineno,mcode 
        FROM dbo.complainVehicle 
        WHERE compno = @compno 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT compno,recoverydt,recoverytime,statuscode 
        FROM dbo.complainRecovery
        WHERE compno =  @compno   
    END
END
```

Second, you must add the appropriate parameter type in your C# code:

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add(
    "@compno", 
    System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Since the parameter is declared as `INT` in the stored procedure definition, you need to use `System.Data.SqlDbType.Int` and provide a valid integer value by calling `int.Parse(textBox1.Text)`.

Refer to [T-SQL Stored Procedure Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) for more information on creating stored procedures and parameter options

Comment: can you please elaborate more , i didnt get it properly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to declare your procedure with a parameter, then you probably want to use EXISTS to check each table, something like this;

```
alter procedure [dbo].[complainVehicle_sp] (@compno int)
as

if (exists (select 1 from dbo.complainVehicle where compno = @compno ) )
begin
    select compno,compdate,regno,engineno,mcode from dbo.complainVehicle 
    where compno =  @compno 
end
else
if (exists (select 1 from dbo.complainRecovery where compno = @compno ) )
begin
   select compno,recoverydt,recoverytime,statuscode from dbo.complainRecovery
   where compno =  @compno   
end
```

You also need to specify the type of the parameter correctly;

```
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@compno", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks Rhys i have tried your method and its working speedy fast .. thanks a lot once again